# Comparitive exposure to spike protein between mRNA vaccines and an actual Covid infection

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, virus, covid, mrna

Do we have any data or estimation regarding the relative spike protein exposure between an mRNA vaccine and an actual Covid infection?

This is a complicated question.

Assume two identical humans are there, one gets mRNA vaccine and one gets an actual Covid infection.

---

1. Now how much covid cells is the infected person exposed to during the course of the disease? The peak virion load is about 1 to 100 billion in Covid inflected patients. [Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7685332/). But this is a snap shot of peak load, we need area under curve to know total load over the period of infection. See the below [figure](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acssensors.1c00312)

[image]

**2. How does this compare to the total amount of spike protiens generated by mRNA vaccines in the body?**

These are the previous links I got but I didn't find the relevant data here

[Is Moderna Really Better Than Pfizer—Or Is It Just a Higher Dose?](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2021/10/pfizer-moderna-dose-which-vaccine-best/620501/)

[SARS-CoV-2 structure and replication characterized by in situ cryo-electron tomography](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.06.23.167064v2.full)

[The total number and mass of SARS-CoV-2 virions](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2665-2?error=cookies_not_supported&code=548f7d18-8a9c-40b0-94eb-aa48955a733a)

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer - a large part of the viral output will be "outside" the body - into the lung spaces of the lungs, into the gut lumen as the virus replicates mostly in the epithelial tissues. There is some immune exposure from this, but characterizing just how much is in the impossible category. We can do a first-order calculation of how many transcripts are injected per vaccine dose and how many RNA are produced in an infection though...

Comment: ...see last part of this answer by me [here for viruses](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31369/lack-of-studies-on-small-doses-of-chlorine-dioxide-as-treatment-for-diseases/31379#31379) and [here for RNA per vaccine on Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100592/how-many-mrna-strands-are-in-a-single-dose-of-the-covid-19-vaccines/100603#100603) respectively

Comment: @bob1 thanks a lot. Do you know how many spikes per covid viron cell?? And how many spike protiens does one mRNA is capable of generating before deteriorating? We already know at peak infection there are 10^9 to 10^11 cells in body.

Comment: @HariKumar cells? Do you mean virions? Try [this](https://elifesciences.org/articles/57309) for some info.

Comment: @bob1 thank you. Is there any way to estimate the total spike protiens created by a single mRNA before it deteriorates?

Comment: @HariKumar I don't know off the top of my head. I'm sure someone will have done it, so have a look on pubmed.

Comment: bob1 I'm sorry that information is not present anywhere

Comment: @bob1 please try to answer this. There is 
a bounty now. I just want to know how much spike protien per mRNA on average.

Comment: @HariKumar if the data isn't there, then there isn't an answer, so no point in me answering. You could look up data on average number of proteins produced per mRNA in general, but I think you will find it varies wildly and is hopelessly inaccurate, as we don't have any great quantifiable methods of counting protein number.

Comment: @bob1 After trying to search for it, I think it is just one. One spike protien per mRNA as the mRNA get opened and spliced, I think it gets degraded after only one protien.

Comment: @HariKumar It would be very unusual in biology more broadly for an mRNA copy to make only a single protein molecule. I would look at some of the earlier bench work on mRNA vaccines rather than clinical trials.

Comment: @BryanKrause any link you can put here?? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @HariKumar I don't have a particular paper in mind, just a suggestion on where to start looking. You might look for protein *mass* instead of count; you can get count from the molecular weight.